# MVC Annotation validation Remove data-val attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

I have model property:

```
public int? RegionId { get; set; }
```

I create dropdownlist in view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RegionId, Model.Regions)
```

In html:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field RegionId must be a number." 
</select>
```

I need to remove the attribute data-val-number, because in a particular case it not right for me.

I try in Application_Start:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

Also note RegionId is nullable.

How I can remove this attribute on server-side code? (not javascript)

Comment: What do you plan to put in the RegionId property?  It is an integer so you aren't going to be able to put a none numeric value into it.

Comment: I want be able put in the RegionId null value.

Comment: Are you have *Required* attribute on *RegionId*?

Comment: I need add him, but data-val-number validation works earlier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In List need add this item:

> new SelectListItem {Text =SiteResources.NotSelected, Selected = true,
>   **Value = ""**} //(not Value=null)

And this item will be valid for data-val-number

Another way In Application_Start:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider());
```

But apparently disable implicit DataAnnotation validation for all simple types.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment by AlexC, if your model expect an integer then you'll need to pass a number. You can avoid to get the validation message by removing the **ValidationFor** helper, but until the type doesn't match then the **Model.IsValid** will never be true.
If you want to bind a null value to a control, you can do it and your **Model.Regions** will be something like this

```
"--Please Select--", Value: null
"US", Value:"1",
"Asia", Value:"2"
```

Comment: In Model.Regions i put: new SelectListItem {Text =SiteResources.NotSelected, Selected = true, Value = null}. But when choose this item in page i see "The field RegionId must be a number."

Comment: new SelectListItem {Text =SiteResources.NotSelected, Selected = true, Value = ""} is validated! Good!